# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

Tags: python, encoding

I want to encode my list into Bytes. How can I do that ?
My code

```
import socket
import psutil
import platform
import os


def my_function():
    system_info = []
    system_info.append("CPU TIMES: " + str(psutil.cpu_times()))
    system_info.append("Total CPUs: " + str(psutil.cpu_count()))
    system_info.append("Total CPU Stats: " + str(psutil.cpu_stats()))
    system_info.append("CPU Frequency: " + str(psutil.cpu_freq()))
    system_info.append("Virtual Memory: " + str(psutil.virtual_memory()))
    system_info.append("Disk Partitions: " + str(psutil.disk_partitions()))
    system_info.append(
        "Machine: " + str(system_info.append("Disk Partitions: " + str(platform.node()))))
    system_info.append("Node: " + str(platform.node()))
    system_info.append("Processor: " + str(platform.processor()))
    return system_info


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432
arr = []
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        data = my_function()
        print(data)
        [arr.append(bytes(element, 'utf-8')) for element in data] #encoding here but getting error
conn.sendall(arr)
```

I am trying to use `Bytes(array, 'utf-8')` to encode the array but to no avail and getting the error that a byte like object is required. How can I convert List to this Byte Like Object

Comment: A list can't be directly turned into bytes. Use a data format list JSON, or pickle

Comment: so if everything is a binary buffer you should be able to just do...
arr = b''

then add them with

arr+=element

then encode as utf at the end..

Comment: Please  always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Your [mre] should include an example of the data - `data` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You get a List from `my_function`. You can convert the elements to bytes nearly as you wrote it, but do not append them to a list. Just join the list with some bytes.

```
list_of_bytes = [bytes(element, 'utf-8') for element in data]
b'<some separator>'.join(list_of_bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this:

```py
arr = list(map(lambda e: bytes(e,"utf-8"), data)
```

But if the problem is the element you are trying to convert is a list, then use nested for loops. Example:

```py
arr = []
for element in data:
    try:
        arr.append(element)
    except:
        arr2 = []
        for i in element:
            arr2.append(bytes(i, "utf-8"))
        arr.append(arr2)
```

And I think you should indent the last line(conn.sendall) two times that it'll be inside of second with statement.

Comment: Or you could use a list comprehension: `[bytes(stuff,'utf-8') for stuff in data]`. But this is what the OP has in the example.

Comment: `I'm not sure but try this`  - please be sure when you answer. ... test it.